# Load JS and CSS from Wordpress plugins after AJAX request

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, history.js

I am using [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) and [Ajaxify](https://github.com/AbacusPowers/ajaxify_s) to refresh content on my Wordpress site. Everything is working fine. Content in my selected div gets refreshed, menus update, etc.

But Javascript- and CSS-files from plugins are not being loaded if I enter a page, which normally would load their required files using wp_enqueue_script (e.g. WP-Forms). It works if I hard reload these sites.

Example: I am on my front-page and use a menu link to navigate to another page, where a contact form is (WP-Forms). Content gets refreshed, required scripts and stylesheets won't load.

I am a total beginner, but I guess that these two functions should handle this request?! But they are not working obviously…

```
// Fetch the scripts
$scripts = $dataContent.find('.document-script');
    if ( $scripts.length ) {
    $scripts.detach();
 }
```

...

```
// Add the scripts
$scripts.each(function(){
    var $script = $(this), scriptText = $script.text(), scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
    if ( $script.attr('src') ) {
        if ( !$script[0].async ) { scriptNode.async = false; }
        scriptNode.src = $script.attr('src');
    }
        scriptNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptText));
    contentNode.appendChild(scriptNode);
});
```

So my question is:
How can I conditionally load these JS and CSS plugin-files without adding them all to my functions.php using wp_enqueue_script?

I tried [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#The_post-load_JavaScript_Event)

```
jQuery( document.body ).trigger( 'post-load' );
```

on ajax.success but it is not doing anything.

Thanks for your help in advance.